# find the given limit $L$?

Tags: real-analysis

> Given $f$ be  positive   and   continious  on $[0,1]$. Find 
>   $$L=\lim_{p \rightarrow  0}   \left( \int_{0}^{1} (f(x))^p dx\right)^{1/p}  $$

My attempt  : I thinks  it will be $\max \{ f(x) : x \in [0,1]\}$

Is its  true ?

Comment: That's not it. Although it is the result as $p \to +\infty$.

Comment: okss i thinks it will  be same  in $p$ tend to $0$ also @xbh

Comment: Any details indicate your guess?